# Datatables, delete added row?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm testing a new table with dataTables, I've got it to display the data how I want so now I'm adding options to add, edit and delete rows. I'm not using editor.
I'd like to use jquery, datatables commands and a little help :)

My Table layout looks like this.

```
<table class='display' id='staff'>
<thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>StaffID</th><th>Department</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id='f6150b00'><td>Rod</td><td>3121</td><td>Physics</td></tr>
    <tr id='0a190b00'><td>Jane</td><td>3122</td><td>Music</td></tr>
    <tr id='621b0b00'><td>Freddy</td><td>3123</td><td>Drama</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The form is generated from a database query and the TR ID is unique to each staff member.

I'm initialising dataTables with :

```
 oTable = $('#staff').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true, "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50], [10, 25, 50]]
});
```

I'm marking a row as selected or not using :

```
$('#staff').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
        else {
            oTable.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    } );
```

I've created three buttons, add, edit and delete and are using them to test how to how interact with the rows.

Highlighting a row and clicking **DELETE** does delete that row. The code I'm using for that is :

```
var sel = $('#staff tr.selected').attr('id')
    oTable.fnDeleteRow( oTable.$('#' + sel)[0] );
```

Clicking **EDIT** sometimes edits the highlighted row, other times it doesn't.
The code I have for that is :

```
var sel = $('#staff tr.selected').attr('id')
$('#staff').dataTable().fnUpdate('COL1', $('tr#' + sel)[0], 0 );
$('#staff').dataTable().fnUpdate('COL2' , $('tr#' + sel)[0], 1 );
$('#staff').dataTable().fnUpdate('COL3' , $('tr#' + sel)[0], 2 );
```

In this test EDIT just changes the row to have COL1, COL2, COL3 values.

Clicking **ADD** does add a new row using :

```
var addRow = $('#staff').dataTable().fnAddData( ['one', 'two', 'three' ]);
var newRow = $('#staff').dataTable().fnSettings().aoData[addRow[0]].nTr;
newRow.setAttribute('id','new000001');
```

Again as this is a test I'm presetting the values and giving the row's TR and ID of new0000001

If I try to delete the newly added row it won't delete.

I'm trying to work out why EDIT sometimes works and other times doesn't and why DELETE fails every time on a newly added row.

Can anyone help with this ?

Thanks

Comment: Just trying to sort a codepen out.

Comment: The intermittant issue is resolved.My buttons were made of images and text and I was doing an onClick on either of them. Some times I was clicking just were I wasn't checking. Changing it to use the full button has resolved. it